# TargetConfig Property cannot contain JSON-like string?

Tags: lightning-web-components, spring-20

## STR

- Create an LWC
- Give it a property in its target config of type "string"
- Add the LWC to a lightning record page, and insert `{ }` into the property
- Save (and activate) the page
- Load a record which would use the page

## Expected

I expected the page to load and for the LWC to have the property set to the string value "{ }"

## Actual

The page does not load at all. The entire page is replaced with:

"**Looks like there's a problem.**

Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID shown here and any other related details."

[image: Image of error message]

## Further Research

I've found that the code will work as expected (i.e. the property is set correctly) on a Winter '20 org, however Spring '20 (Patch 3.3) will produce the bug.

Escaping the opening curly brace appears to make it work, however there seems to be a discrepancy between how the **Preview** (Page Builder) page interprets it and how the **Actual** page interprets it. Using `\{ }` will result in the property being set to `\{ }` on the preview page, but it will be set to `{ }` on the actual page.

The string `{}` works, so something needs to be between the curly braces for the error to occur.

`{ } text` will fail, but `text { }` and `text { } text` will not, so it seems to have something to do with the string starting with curly braces.

`{ "text" }` will fail but `{ "text"` will not, so the curly brace needs to be closed for the error to occur.

## Example

miniLwc.html

```
<template></template>
```

miniLwc.js

```js
import { api, LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class MiniLwc extends LightningElement { @api testValue; }
```

miniLwc.js-meta.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>47.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <property name="testValue" label="Test Value" type="string"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: Apart from `{}` none of the example texts are valid JSON. Is it that you don't want JSON but instead want curly brackets (braces) in your string? My guess is Salesforce is looking for a leading "{" and automatically deserializes the value as JSON in that case. If the "{" is anywhere but the start, does it always work?